# How to show toolbar in bokeh graph

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, toolbar

I am having trouble adding a toolbar icon to my code. The following is the code I have below, I want to be able to see the tool bar icons for each of the tools.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_file, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, HoverTool,BoxSelectTool,WidgetBox
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs, Panel
import csv
output_file('btcnov1.html')  # Render to static HTML, or 
output_notebook()  # Render inline in a Jupyter Notebook
%matplotlib inline

btc412 = pd.read_excel('11-01 412-605.xlsx',sheet_name="Sheet1")
now1 = pd.DataFrame(btc412, columns=['size','unix'])
now2 = pd.DataFrame(btc412, columns=['unix','price','size'])
x = now1.loc[now1["size"] == 31, "unix"]
y = now1.loc[now1["size"] == 31, "size"]
z= now2.loc[now2["size"] == 31, "unix"]
w=now2.loc[now2["size"] == 31, "price"]
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('index', "$index"),
   ("(x,y)", "(@x, @y)"),
("(z,w)", "(@z, @w)"),
])

tools=["pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,hover,xbox_zoom"]
# Set up the figure(s)
fig = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=900,tools=tools,
             title='BTC NOV 1, 4:12-6:05 am',
             x_axis_label='Unix', y_axis_label='Size',
             toolbar_location=None)

fig.circle(x, y, 
         color='#CE1141', legend='size')

fig.line(z,w, color='#CE1141', legend='price')


show(fig)
```

I want to be able to see the toolbar for the HoverTool, select tool, etc. Also, what do I add to save the plot??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have explicitly asked for there not to be a toolbar, by setting `toolbar_location=None`. So, if you want a toolbar, don't do that.